# How to fetch only value available key data array from postdata?

Tags: php

I want to make one update array from my APIs postdata like below i have received :

Postdata :

```
array (
         [email] => 
         [name] => abc
         [number] => 12345
         [address] =>
);
```

I need to filer above array and need to below expected output :

```
array (
             [name] => abc
             [number] => 12345
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php

$data = array (
    'email' => null,
    'name' => 'abc',
    'number' => 12345,
    'address' => null
);

$postdata = array_filter($data);

print_r($postdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_filter to remove empty elements:

```
$array=array (
    'email' => '',
    'name' => abc,
    'number' => 12345,
    'address' =>''
);
$array=array_filter($array);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers submitted are a great solution for your problem, but there could be situations where you don't want to omit/ignore the '0' or 0 values from your array or ignore all the empty characters. In such a situation, default `array_filter` can cause unexpected results.

```
$arr = array('1','2', '3', '0');

print_r(array_filter($arr)); // Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Again there is an odd case where the empty characters are more than one.

```
$arr = array('1', ' ', '2', '3', '0'); // two spaces at index 1

print_r(array_filter($arr)); // Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => [2] => 2 [3] => 3 )
```

So in such a situation, you can take the help of the second argument of the `array_filter` method. You can pass other built-in methods name provided by PHP or
pass an anonymous method.

```
$arr = array('1', ' ', '2', '3', '0');

$arr = array_filter($arr, function($a) {
    return trim($a) !== "";
});

print_r($arr); // Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 0 )
```